# События "FormMouseWheelDown" или "FormMouseWheelUp" обрабатываються дважды. Почему?

Tags: delphi

Изначально Label1.Caption приравниваем к нулю.
Имееться вот такой исходный код:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label1.Caption)+1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label1.Caption)-1);
end;
```

У меня задача отловить сколько раз было совершено действие скролом "Вверх" и "Вниз" и запустить соответствующую функцию. Иходник работает но почему он выполняться дважды???
И как сделать чтоб он выполнялся один раз?

Comment: Нормально все работает. Вниз +1, верх -1.

Comment: Извините забыл сказать... 
Все верно +1 и -1 срабатывает если на форме нет каких либо других компонентов. 
Но если вы внесёте компонент Edit или Button и заведомо перейдёте на компоненты "Tab-ом" или просто щёлкните мышкой то тут же начинает считать +2 и -2.

Comment: @p_redator, не забудьте принять верный ответ.

Comment: У меня аналогичная проблема с приложением на С++: MouseWheelDown & MouseWheelUp обрабатываются дважды на один шаг колесика мыши.
Есть ли в С аналог Handled := True; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь в каждый обработчик:

```
Handled := True;
```

чтобы получилось так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
  Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label1.Caption)+1);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
  Label1.Caption:=IntToStr(StrToInt(Label1.Caption)-1);
end;
```

Будет считать только один раз.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает как часы! На компонентах Edit или Button данный метод работает, а в DBGrid этот исходник не прорабатывает процедуры "FormMouseWheelDown" и "FormMouseWheelUp". Не подскажите что нужно сделать? или для этого нужно новый вопрос создавать?

Comment: Стандартное поведение скролинга в DBGrid не зависит от обработчиков событий OnMouseWheelDown и OnMouseWheelUp на форме. Как решить вопрос сходу не подскажу, потому что давно не использую его в своих проектах.

Comment: А может подскажете какой вы используете компонент вместо DBGrid ?

Comment: Для простых таблиц cxDBGrid (пакет DevExpress). Он поддерживает связку с источником данных через DataSource. Если нужен вариант с гибкой кастомизацией то VirtualStringTree (из [VirtualTreeView][1]).

  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/

Comment: А вы уверены что в пакете cxDBGrid есть "скроллинг" и его можно отловить??? 
http://www.rxlib.ru/rx/rxDBAware/RxDBGrid/index.htm 
Здесь описаны Events ( События ) Key events и нечего подобного там не описываеться 
Пробовал  установить EhLib делаю все по интсрукции нажимаю Compile потом Instal и он мне говорит 
"Cannot load package Ehlib60. It contains unit DBgridEh  which is also contained dclusr60"

Answer (score 0):

Вообще советую в этих целях использовать компонент `UpDown`, находящийся на панели `Win32`.

Comment: Возможно чего-то недопонимаю, но как можно использовать компонент `UpDown` если у меня задача отловить скроллинг и желательно чтоб процедура выполнялась один раз.

Comment: Можно установить у компонента UpDown В свойстве associate нужный
вам Edit, потом вы должны отлавливать скроллинг в форме событиями
"FormMouseWheelDown" и "FormMouseWheelUp", ну и наконец если
скроллинг пойман, то устанавливаете фокус ввода на Edit1.
(Edit1.SetFocus())

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик, но события "FormMouseWheelDown" и "FormMouseWheelUp" отлавливаються без компонента UpDown.